# Sharding do not balance data to two shards

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongomapper, mongo-java

I have added two shards as follows:

```
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/serv1:27017,serv2:27017,serv3:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/serv3:27017,serv4:27017,serv5:27017" }
```

I have sharded my collection posts as follows:

databases:

```
{  "_id" : "mypost",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }

             mypost.posts
                        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                        chunks:
                                rs0    2
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 1)
```

My question is even though I use hashed key on _id and inserted 34MB of data why data is always fetched from shard 1 only and no chunk is moved to shard 2.

when I do

```
db.posts.find().explain() i get:

{
        "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
        "shards" : {
                "rs0/serv1:27017,serv2:27017,serv3:27017" : [
                        {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 1000,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 1000,
                                "nscanned" : 1000,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 0,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 4,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "server" : "serv1:27017"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "n" : 1000,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 1000,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1000,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000,
        "millisShardTotal" : 4,
        "millisShardAvg" : 4,
        "numQueries" : 1,
        "numShards" : 1,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "millis" : 5
}
```

How can my data be sent to both the shard automatically.

sh.status()

```
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "version" : 3,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
        "currentVersion" : 4,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("50fde9a8552b8ce5c47c8ead")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/serv1:27017,serv2:27017,serv3:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/serv4:27017,serv5:27017,serv6:27017" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "myposts",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
                myposts.posts
                        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                        chunks:
                                rs0    1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

status after delete of collection---------------------

```
{  "_id" : "myposts",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
                myposts.posts
                        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                        chunks:
                                rs0    2
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 1)
```

Comment: sh.status() output? You seem to have a shard key that only consists of the value `0` which is odd

Comment: @Sammaye can you explain a bit detail?

Comment: @Sammaye my id field values are all diffrenet:{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f8") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3f9") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3fa") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ab0f8bbcf1bfe2536dc3fb") }

Comment: What I meant was can you first add the output of `sh.status()`?

Comment: @Sammaye sh.status() is the output shown in first two grey, it is broken and made two parts to be more clear.

Comment: I have added it again

Comment: Ok you only have one chunk, I think you might not have enough data for splitting to occur, that might be way you saw the behaviour you did, after balancing the data was merged, try adding 1,000,000 rows

Comment: @Sammaye when i dropped the collection and added again i got two chunks but in the same shard:        {  "_id" : "myposts",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
                myposts.posts
                        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                        chunks:
                                rs0    2
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 1)

Comment: modified the same in the question

Comment: And if you give it some time? Balancing is not instantaneous

Comment: @Sammaye why it is adding two chunks in the same shard when I added the collection second time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look over the [Sharding Mechanics](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/) documentation (and if you are mongodb 2.2 or later), you'll see that for fewer than 20 chunks, you'll need to have an imbalance of 2 for the balancer to move chunks.

I wouldn't expect you to have any balancing of chunks until you have a minimum of 4 chunks.

Is there a reason why you have so few chunks defined or are you going to wait for enough data to roll in to have the balancer slice and dice things for you?